# Nullable Class as a Property is not Nullable. Why?

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, c#-10.0

I have a class that I created where a property is another class I wrote.  I am being warned that my property is non-nullable and I don't understand why.  Aren't all properties of nullable classes nullable?

```
  public class Yeast
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public Code Brand { get; set; }
    public Code Style { get; set; }
    public string? Trademark { get; set; }
    public int? TempMin { get; set; }
    public int? TempMax { get; set; }
    public double? Alcohol { get; set; }
    public string? Note { get; set; }   
}
```

[image]

```
 /// <inheritdoc cref="ICode"/>
public class Code : ICode
{
    /// <inheritdoc cref="ICode.Id"/>
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ICode.ParentId"/>
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ICode.Literal"/>
    public string? Literal { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ICode.Enabled"/>
    public bool? Enabled { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ICode.Description"/>
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}

public interface ICode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Code Unique Identifier
    /// </summary>
    int? Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Code Foreign Key
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Optional</remarks>
    int? ParentId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Literal Name of Code
    /// </summary>
    string? Literal { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of Code
    /// </summary>
    string? Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enabled for Use
    /// </summary>
    bool? Enabled { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you have [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) enabled in your project, but are not aware of that fact.

With nullable reference types enabled, when you define a property to be of type `Code` you are actually telling the compiler that it will never be null, and the compiler will try to assert that analyzing your code and generating warnings.

If `null` is a valid and expected value of your `Brand` property, then simply declare it as `Code?`. If not, then you need to guarantee that it will always have a not-null value once its containing class is instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that if you do `new Yeast().Brand.Id` you'll get a NullReferenceException because Brand is null - but you declared it wouldn't be.

So either the constructor needs to set Brand to a non-null Code value, or you need to mark it as nullable so the compiler can flag it in the consuming code (i.e. say that `new Yeast().Brand` needs to handle the possibility of a null value).